# How do I change the startup page on a WP7 Silverlight app?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have added a new XAML page to my WP7 app and I need the application to startup on this new page. How do I do that ?

I cannot find MainPage (which is the current / default start page) referenced anywhere in App.xaml or App.xaml.cs.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

In WMAppManifest.xml you'll find the following.

```
<Tasks>
  <DefaultTask Name="_default" NavigationPage="MainPage.xaml" />
</Tasks>
```

Change as appropriate.

Comment: I want to open a link e.g. http://www.google.com/ in web browser (same as web view in android) after the splash screen finish loading in wp7?