# How to change the startup page of a WP7 Application

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am having an WP7 application in which I need to change the Startup page depending upon if the user is already registered or not. Suppose if user is registered then I need to redirect him to welcome page if not then to register page.

I have tried a couple of ways below is my code but it gives me an argument dispose exception.

To achieve above feature I wrote Navigation code in my MainPage.xaml constructor. Checked if the User Registration info is not in isolated storage then will redirect to other page.

```
    private void IsAgreeed()
    {
        try
        {
            isoStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
            if (!isoStorage.FileExists("DataBase/MyPhoneNumber.txt"))
            {
                this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/EULA.xaml", UriKind.Relative));                   
            }
            else
            {
                return;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());

        }
    }
```

Above code works properly when I use it first time but if I Close the Application and restart it again it throws exception argument dispose exception.

Thanks;
 nil

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I change the startup page on a WP7 Silverlight app ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3892271/how-do-i-change-the-startup-page-on-a-wp7-silverlight-app)

Comment: Bah, wrong link.  Here's the existing question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4303403/windows-phone-7-sign-in-screen-redirect

Comment: Try  :  using (IsolatedStorageFile isoStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{ // your code }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Peter Torr covers page redirections quite well here. Two methods are offered with relative merits covered. Edit: Note you can redirect to a login page, rather then employing the popup suggestion for login handling.

[Redirecting an initial navigation - Peter Torr's Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ptorr/archive/2010/08/28/redirecting-an-initial-navigation.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0)

I'd also recommend familiarising with his accompanying post on places here.

[Introducing the concept of “Places” - Peter Torr's Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ptorr/archive/2010/08/28/introducing-the-concept-of-places.aspx)

This address back stack handling (certification consideration) and addresses scenarios such as login pages.

Comment: Thanks guys ... I looked at these and implemented these using the UriMapper way as suggested by Peter but still I need bit more complex feature which I need to implement. What I am trying is first if user is not registered then redirect him to a Eula page ie Eula.xaml and then to register.xaml and then to MainPage.xaml but as I have mapped MainPage.xaml to Eula so when I redirect user from register to MainPage.xaml it gets redirected to Eula again. So how should I do it ?

Answer (score 1):

Peter Torr explained 2 techniques for your purpose.

[Redirecting an initial navigation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ptorr/archive/2010/08/28/redirecting-an-initial-navigation.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0)

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this I put up MainPageorEula.xaml and got the functionality required.