# Redirecting my initial page

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change startup page on WP7 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9247908/how-to-change-startup-page-on-wp7-application)

I got a problem in navigating the xml, What I exactly need is I need to call an xml page from `WMAPPmanifest.xml` when the application is installed first, once the application is installed the `WMAPPmanifest.xml` should call to other xml.

The thing is I need to be redirected to one page when the application is installed, this page should be showed only one when he enters the app after the installation and once after that the application. how can I do this in windows, I am using C# for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 for development.

Thanks.

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9247908/how-to-change-startup-page-on-wp7-application

Comment: ya thanks for the reply actually tat was bit similar but my prob is the first page should be shown only once, when the user opens our application after the installation otherwise it should go to page2 directly, this is the prob for me. 

i called page1 from manifest file so each time when i open the application it takes page1 as main page and it was opened first but as said i need to call this page1 only on first opening after installation, after tat it should go to page2. so how can i procede it ?? thanks

Comment: Store a flag in isolated storage on first run of the app. On subsequent executions, the flag tells Page1 to redirect to Page2. You'll also have to remove Page1 from the navigation stack.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can achieve this.

First, I would suggest you to create one `UserControl` and place your OneTime Page's code in it
And when the app loads let it go to the Actual home page and there you check the flag from IsolatedStore and based on the flag decide whether to show the UserControl or not.

Secondly,
Follow the code in the link which is mentioned in the first comment and decide which page to redirect based on following code.

For both the above options, you need to handle a flag from IsolatedStorage.

```
var appSettings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
if(appSettings.Contains("pageflag"))
{
   destinationPage = "/ActualHomePage.xaml";
}
else
{
   destinationPage = "/OneTimePage.xaml";
   appSettings.Add("pageflag", 0);
}
```

Hope it's clear!!