# Redirect to certain pages based on variable, on app startup

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change startup page on WP7 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9247908/how-to-change-startup-page-on-wp7-application)

By default a windows phone app navigates to 'MainPage.xaml' when your app starts up. How to I intervene this by redirecting to other pages based on certain variables.

For example, go to page1.xaml if var a is true, otherwise go to page2.xaml...

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

what i will do is this i app.xmal.cs file `

```
    private void Application_Launching(object sender, LaunchingEventArgs e)
    {
        SetupDefautPage();
    }

    private void Application_Activated(object sender, ActivatedEventArgs e)
    {            
        SetupDefautPage();
    }`
```

and my void `SetupDefautPage` look like this:

```
 void SetupDefautPage()
    {
        if ((DefaultPage !=false)&&(DefaultPage !=true)) 
        {
            (Application.Current as App).DefaultPage = false;
        }

        if (DefaultPage==false)
         {
            ((App)Application.Current).RootFrame.Navigate(new Uri("/TermUsePage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
         }
        else if(DefaultPage==true)
         {
           ((App)Application.Current).RootFrame.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
         }


    }
```

It just an idea, i hope it is good for you case