# windows phone 8 change start page according to result from sqlite database

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

i want to change the start page of my app according to the result from sqlite db. I have removed the nevigationpage parameter from appmenifist file. In App.xaml.cs in application launching function i am using

```
            Conn = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(DB_PATH);
            var BabayData = Conn.QueryAsync<baby>("SELECT * FROM baby");

            if (BabayData.Count == 0)
            {
                RootFrame.Navigate(new Uri("/Profile.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
            }
            else
            {
                RootFrame.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
            }
```

But it shows wrong result. (I checked, query doesn't give any results.) How can i solve this issue that if there is a baby MainPage.xaml shuld b start page.

Regards

Comment: What's the error you're getting now?

Comment: As i said i am not getting any error just the result is not as expected.

Comment: What you mean by a baby page here?

Comment: Sorry ! i didn't get you. I just wana query db for baby. and if there is a baby then "Mainpage.xaml" should be start page otherwise "Profile.xaml".

Comment: Possible Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9247908/how-to-change-startup-page-on-wp7-application

Comment: @SeeSharp i am having trouble with my database result. if i pass count "0" or "1" it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think your app is starting before it connects to the database. So u can create a prelogin page or try this:

```
private async void Application_Launching(object sender, LaunchingEventArgs e) 
        { 
            try 
            { 
                await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(DB_PATH); 
                Connection = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(DB_PATH); 
            } 
            catch (FileNotFoundException) 
            { 
              CreateDbAsync(); // create if not exists
            } 
        }
```

[example here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/SQLite-for-Windows-Phone-8-8ff3beaf)

Comment: I found th issue and resolved it. Problem was with my connection thanks for ur help. I have another question [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27224595/windows-phone-8-sqlite-async-issue?noredirect=1#comment42927573_27224595)  Can ypu please help me on this too.